# R parSapply does not recognize the function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to parallelize a user function using parSapply. I followed some tutorials and I figured it out the below code. However, the parSapply function returns an error:

```
library(parallel)

dummy_function <- function(x,y){
  x_ <- runif(1000, 0, x)
  y_ <- runif(1000, 0, y)
  return(median(x_*y_))
}

#it works with replicate
replicate(1000, dummy_function(2,5))


cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(MASS))
clusterSetRNGStream(cl)
clusterExport(cl, c("dummy_function"))

#it does not work with parSappply
results <- parSapply(cl, 1:1000, dummy_function(2,5))

# Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
#   'dummy_function(2, 5)' is not a function, character or symbol

stopCluster(cl)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a lamdba function

```
results <- parSapply(cl, 1:1000, function(u) dummy_function(x = 2, y = 5))
```

-checking

```
> length(results)
[1] 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue: correct syntax is `sapply(vec, fun)` and not `sapply(vec, fun(arg1, arg2)`.

So, given your set up, I would move the `2` and `5` as default values for the arguments of `dummy_function`:

```
dummy_function <- function(x=2, y=5) { # <-- changes made here
    x_ <- runif(1000, 0, x)
    y_ <- runif(1000, 0, y)
    return(median(x_*y_))
}
```

Then you can run `replicate` without passing the args:

```
replicate(1000, dummy_function())
```

And then you run `parSapply` (similarly without args):

```
results <- parSapply(cl, 1:1000, dummy_function)
```

Comment: It wouldn't work when the OP wants to change the arguments. Check `parSapply(cl, 1:1000, dummy_function, x = 5, y = 10)
Error in clusterApply(cl = cl, x = splitList(X, nchunks), fun = lapply,.`  The issue is that `FUN` takes a function

Comment: @akrun -- that's because you're changing the arguments the wrong way. You can't list both the `x` and `y` arguments in `sapply` (or `parSapply`) because `sapply` is already trying to use the `1:1000` as an input.  The error you receive isn't due to my approach; it's due to you trying to input 3 things (1:1000, x=5, y=10) into a function that only takes 2 args.

Comment: My point is that how you will pass x and y differently than the default option you have in the function?  Or else if I understand your function, the default option have to be changed everytime when somebody needs to change.  I understand the `sapply` and `parSapply` and that is the reason I said your `dummy_function` wouldn't work if the OP decides to use it unless he/she wants to wrap it in a lambda function